# Python retrieve windows service "Log On As" attribute

Tags: python, windows, service

I have a lot of servers where certain service is  launched, let's call it `service_name`. And on each server this service is launched under different Active Directory accounts, like `domain\username`. 
Is there anyway to get `domain\username` information with Python on the server knowing the `service_name`?

Comment: You can query the account name used for a service either locally or remotely. From the command line, you can run sc.exe with its `qc` command to query the service config. Or directly call the service APIs `OpenSCManager`, `OpenService`, and [`QueryServiceConfig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684932). The queried [service config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684950) has the account name for a user-mode service in the `lpServiceStartName` field.

Comment: ok, seems like win32service is the answer. I can define the 'log on as' attribute of the services on the local machine, but how to do it on remote server...